# Any method to get constant for HTTP and HTTPS values

Tags: java, spring, rest

Is there a class whene HTTP and HTTPs constant value is defined. As of now I have created a custom class.

```
   public static class UrlConstants {

    private UrlConstants() {
        super();
    }

    /** The Constant HTTP. */
    public static final String HTTP = "http";
}
```

Comment: This question will get closed, if you don't put in clear details what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

A little clunky, but these work.

`String.valueOf(org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpURL.DEFAULT_SCHEME)`
`String.valueOf(org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpsURL.DEFAULT_SCHEME)`

There's also `org.mortbay.jetty.HttpSchemes.HTTP` and `org.mortbay.jetty.HttpSchemes.HTTPS`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell (as of JDK 8 which I have handy), the best you can do *within* the Java JDK is

`javax.print.attribute.standard.ReferenceUriSchemesSupported`

which provides a number of URI-Schemes:

```
import javax.print.attribute.standard.ReferenceUriSchemesSupported;
// ...
System.out.println(ReferenceUriSchemesSupported.HTTPS); // => "https"
```

Of course, it also has `GOPHER`, `NNTP`, `NEWS`, and a few other out-of-date schemes, but it *does* provide what you want.

Other answers on the web suggest other frameworks, many of which *do* define the two protocols.

Otherwise, you just need something like this:

```
package demo;

public enum Scheme {
    HTTP("http"),
    HTTPS("https");
    private final String scheme;

    private Scheme(String scheme) {
        this.scheme = scheme;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return scheme;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Apache HttpClient, we have the ENUM UriScheme (org.apache.hc.core5.http.UriScheme)

Answer (score -4):

```
HttpStatus.OK.value() will return the integer value of the status code.
```

Probably this will help your query, this is from `org.springframework.http` package

Comment: I don't want status code. I want a class where http and hhtps constants are defined. As of now I am defining custom constant class

Comment: I am not aware any such class from Spring but you can refer HttpStatus interface from org.apache.http, here all constants enumeration is defined.